# SharePoint 2010 'contentEditable' and Safari on iPad?

Tags: ipad, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm just checking if you know a work-around to the problem where we can't use the contentEditable attribute on iPads? I know we can edit the compact.browser to redirect iPad users to the mobile version but we don't want to do this.

Is there some jQuery magic we can use or any 3rd party app you recommend for a rich experience with SharePoint 2010 and iPad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a rich text component that is based on canvas rather than contentEditable. Unfortunately such a thing doesn't yet exist as far as I am aware, at least not as a ready to use component.

You can use jQuery to update the content in any of SharePoint's editable areas and it will be saved (I know this mostly because it tends to save dynamic stuff I don't want saved), so it is possible to set something up with a textarea and sync script, but probably more work than you are looking for.